# How to read from a file when passing path as an argument using realpath()

Tags: c, realpath

I want to pass an argument of a specific file location using `realpath()` (example: `/var/log/message`) and by using `fprintf` print the content of this file on the terminal.
This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <path>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *fullpath = realpath(argv[1], NULL);
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(fullpath, "r");
    fprintf(fptr, "%s");
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't throw errors, but it also doesn't do what I want it to do.
When I run it e.g. `./test /var/log/message` it will show me this on the terminal:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

#### OS version

```
NAME="Fedora Linux"
VERSION="36
```

#### Compiler

```
gcc
```

Comment: With `fprintf(fptr, "%s");` you attempt to write *to* the file, not read from it. There should be plenty of tutorials on how to read files all over the Internet, not to mention that any decent text-book should have chapters about it.

Comment: As for the problems, have you checked what the functions you call actually *returns*? Both `realpath` ad `fopen` might fail, you need to check for that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not only does `fprintf(fptr, "%s");` write, it's undefined behavior (That can but doesn't have to segfault) because you don't have a string argument for the `%s` format.

Comment: You don't normally need to use `realpath()` to open files specified on the command line.  Simply pass `argv[1]` to `fopen()`.  If you are not going to loop over all the command-line arguments, you should check for `if (argc != 2)`.  You should report errors on standard error, not standard output.

Comment: Not only is `fprintf(fptr, "%s");` writing to a file opened for reading only, it is writing a string, but not specifying which string to write.  The code here is deeply flawed.  Rethink from the ground up.  Check that the function calls all work before using the results.

Comment: Will go back to read more documentation. Thanks all for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Got back to my function and added some more functionality and now it's working by adding argument for it.
What I had to do is to declare that fptr is FILE and c is character type, running a while loop over the file and print its content and with using `fgetc` stream that content to the terminal.

Current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    char c;
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("You need to grant an arg to %s <path>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *fullpath = realpath(argv[1], NULL);
    fptr = fopen(fullpath, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file \n");
        free(fptr);
        exit(0);
    }
    c = fgetc(fptr);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        printf ("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(fptr);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks all for your assistance.

Comment: You still have a memory leak. If you pass `NULL` to `realpath` as second argument it does a `malloc()` for the return value. So, you have to free it, once you are done with it.

Comment: Like so?
Make sense

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  The value of `EOF` does not fit into a `char`.